# How to represent a many to many relationship in a uml class diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have a question about a UML class diagram. Do many to many relationships have a junction table like in ERD diagrams or not? it would make sense for me having a junction table to put the quantity of items in there. Here is what I have but without a junction table[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there is. And it's called associaton class. The notation is like this:

[image]

This is a shortcut for

[image]

The `OrderItem` relates `Item` and `PurchaseOrder` by adding what ever needed (quantity, rebate, etc.) to it.